# Ffmpeg changes major_brand when trimming

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding, video-codecs

I have a workflow where I trim videos like this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 5.000000  -map 0:v -map 0:a? -c:v copy -c:a copy  output.mp4 -y
```

And I noticed that the output video has a different major_brand than the input (input is **mp42** , output is **isom** )

The weird thing is that when I do the trimming command, ffmpeg says the output is mp42:

```
    Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: mp42iso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.27.100
  Duration: 00:02:58.96, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 10015 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, top first), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 9828 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc59.37.100 libx264
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 180 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: mp42iso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.27.100
  Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, top first), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 9828 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc59.37.100 libx264
  Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 180 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
```

But then when I do ffprobe on the output:

```
    Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.27.100
  Duration: 00:02:53.96, start: 0.013000, bitrate: 9590 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, top first), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 9452 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc59.37.100 libx264
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 186 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
```

I'd like to preserve the input major brand. I know I can use the `-brand` flag to set the brand to `mp42`, but I'd like something more generic.
I tried `-movflags use_metadata_tags`   and `-map_metadata 0` , without success.

Is there anything else that I could use to keep the input brand ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The brand in the output file identifies the format specification of the file that ffmpeg writes. By default, that is `isom`. It is not a piece of user metadata, so any metadata related options won't work.

For `mp42`, you'll have to specify brand manually.